# Maximize the difference of the means of two sets

Tags: puzzle

I have a set of real numbers which I'll call set `A`. I have a threshold `t`. I have sets `B` and `C` which are constructed in the following ways: `B` contains every element in `A` which is greater than `t` and `C` contains every element in `A` which is less than or equal to `t`. How should I decide the value of `t` so as to maximize the difference of the means of sets `B` and `C`?

My intuition tells me to have `t` be the mean of set `A`, but I'm not sure this is right.

Comment: There's little to be said in general; certainly $t$ needn't be the mean.  Try it out with some random data.  As a practical matter, since an optimal $t$ can be found in two quick passes through the sorted data, there are no computational difficulties in finding it.

Comment: Could you explain how you would find t through two passes of the data?

Comment: After sorting the data $x_1\le x_2\le \cdots \le x_n$, in the first pass compute the cumulative sums $y_1=x_1; y_i=y_{i-1}+x_i,i=2,\ldots,n$. For each $i=1,2,\ldots,n-1$, the difference of the means is $(y_n-y_i)/(n-i) - y_i/i$: pick the largest of those in a second pass. (You could actually do this in one pass if you compute the total of the data during the sorting procedure.)